# Should the winding number algorithm be able to detect edge points at a square?

Tags: c++, algorithm, polygon, point-in-polygon

I implemented the winding algorithm according to https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?497679-To-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon. During testing I realized that it seems that an edgepoint of a square (so the polygon is a square) doesn't get detected at beeing inside of the polygon. Is this the correct behaviour or am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: The boundary of an object is not considered to be the inside of the object.  In fact this makes the algorithm more robust for corner cases, like the top corner of a 45 degree rectangle. There will be only 1 intersection point with the polygon and thus there will be no line segment with length > 0 that could be considered to be the inside of the polygon

Comment: So I will just have to add an additional check for the edge I guess

Comment: Yes I think you should.  But it can be tricky if you have to generalize to a concave polygon and you find an odd number of intersections. e.g. if you have 3 intersections which of those will be the "single point" and where will the segment be?

Comment: I was thinking about talking the is_left() function of the winding algorithm to check if it on the line and then I need to compare the values of the two polygon points creating the line and my point to see if it is on the actual polygon edge